# Bootstrap navbar and panels disappeared from website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an angular2 website that uses bootstrap and it worked perfectly fine for 2 months. Today many of bootstrap's features just disappeared. Below is the image - the white stripe on the top is where the nav bar used to be - the navbar's title is still there, but color and other items, like login, register etc are not visible (or not there anymore). I've tried to change bootstrap 3.3.7 to 4beta, but the result is still the same...

[image]

That's how it looked before:

[image]

index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image Annotation</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">
  <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous"-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!--script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

navbar.component.html:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Imaging Annotation and Management</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" routerLink="/profile" >Profile</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" routerLink="/anno" >Annotation</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" routerLink="/login" >Login</a></li>
        <li><a *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" href="#" (click)="onLogoutClick()">Logout</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"><a routerLink="/register" >Register</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please share code or your website link where you have navbar issue.

Comment: please see above

Comment: In navbar component, navbar items are visible. Run code snippet and see. If you have issue in website, then need to find the issue in website, currently you code snippet is working.

Comment: Yes, probably because it is ignoring bootstrap classes when run as is... In the website it knows how to run bootstrap, but bootstrap fails to show full navbar somehow. that's how I understand it...

Comment: See page or page view source in browser, your bootstrap css file is included in page, where you have used navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm back in business)) the problem was with this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.css">
```

I switched to standard bootstrap and it now works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```